Tableau - Can we concatenate parameter values into single parameter which will be pass to CUSTOM SQL
I'd like create dynamic parameter which is concatenation of first 4 parameters. It should be dynamically changed which will be passed to CUSTOM SQL latest. Please share your views / solution to handle this scenario.



Parameters are single valued only. Sets can be multi-valued. Do you really need to use Custom SQL? There are usually more options if you use Tableau features and let Tableau generate the SQL. For example, try using a set control to let the user choose their selections and then using the set in a filter.

First off, you would want to be pulling a concatenated calculated field/s based on your parameter inputs, not the parameter itself. Parameters don't work like this in tableau, see this documentation for an extensive list of their functions.
If you are just trying to get the text value of your parameters to plug into a SQL query, convert all the values to string and put them in a calculated field, let's call it [custom SQL txt]:
// "currently selected parameter display name + parameter value + currently
// selected parameter 2 name + parameter value" as a string

[asset name 1] + '~' + STR([input weight 1]) + '|' 
+ [asset name 2] + '~' + STR([input weight 2])

This will work even if you have not linked your parameters to an actual field as it will just grab the display name of the currently selected parameter, however you can edit [custom SQL txt] to grab the actual data values as long as you are filtered to a single asset for EACH one of the asset name inputs.
So rather than parameters you could duplicate your asset name column, rename it to asset 2 and drag both columns to the filter pane. From there, just edit the calculation to swap [parameter name] with [asset name] for both 1 and 2 respectively, then filter to the desired asset for each.
When you go to get your custom SQL query, just pull the text value of the calculated field: [custom SQL txt].
